# Cannot find module 'webpack' whilst deploying on Heroku

Tags: heroku, npm, webpack, deployment

This is the webpack error:

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack: webpack.dev.babel.js, frontendMiddleware.js, server/index.js

Webpack is listed in my dependencies.
The app is working locally with npm start.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you have the whole stack trace? Where is the error being thrown? Perhaps your dependencies are not being installed on Heroku.

Comment: I haven't done a whole stack trace, will do so thanks! The error is being show when I deploy the app on heroku and run 'heroku logs --tail'. Cheers

Comment: Please show us your `package.json`.